# Database and tools for validated BPMs of songs?

Tags: itunes, mp3, music, tags, bpm

I'm a bit picky about ensuring that all of my music has the proper tags in iTunes.  I rip all of my music from CDs or purchase it by the album from Amazon, this provides good coverage.  I then use [Get Lyrical](http://shullian.com/get_lyrical.PHP) to add in lyrics information. What I'm missing is a good source of BPM information.  I've tried various programs such as [MixMeister BPM Analyzer](http://www.mixmeister.com/bpmanalyzer/bpmanalyzer.asp) to calculate the BPM of music, but they're never quite right (There is no way the entirety of Metallica's Black album is 128,000 BPM).

I've found a couple of source of databases with BPMs for music, such as [BPM4DJs.com](http://www.bpm4djs.com/), but they don't have tools to access the data. Is there a database and tool that I can feed a set of tagged MP3s into that will automatically get the BPMs for songs (not some auto-calculated value) and tag my MP3s with the right values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not perfect, but with the plugin [foo_run](http://mp3tag.de/en/fb2k.html) for [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) you could easily launch a web search with your tags
(fb2k is to iTunes what firefox 3.5 is to IE 6...)

So, now that everything is installed, to launch a bm4djs.com search on artist & title with foo_run, add a new service with this path properties (in foobar2000 preferences > tools > run services):

```
http://www.bpm4djs.com/index.php?app_mode=search&search=true&site=1&sv_artist=$replace(%artist%, ,+)&sv_title=$replace(%title%, ,+)&sv_accuracy=tolerant&sv_genere=4&submit=Go
```

for album & title:

```
http://www.bpm4djs.com/index.php?app_mode=search&search=true&site=1&sv_title=$replace(%title%, ,+)&sv_album=$replace(%album%, ,+)&sv_accuracy=tolerant&sv_genere=4&submit=Go
```

for artist alone:

```
http://www.bpm4djs.com/index.php?app_mode=search&search=true&site=1&sv_artist=$replace(%artist%, ,+)&sv_accuracy=tolerant&sv_genere=4&submit=Go
```

for artist & bpm (if your bpm tag name is "BPM"):

```
http://www.bpm4djs.com/index.php?app_mode=search&search=true&site=1&sv_artist=$replace(%artist%, ,+)sv_bpm=%bpm%&sv_accuracy=tolerant&sv_genere=4&submit=Go
```

etc...

You could certainly tweak it better with the foobar2000's [title formatting](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Titleformat_Reference) and a little study of the search url of bpm4dj or any other website...

And, cherry on the cake, foobar2000 recently got a [BPM plugin](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=77142), it's still in early stage but the dev looks motivated.

Comment: This is pretty helpful and I'll take a look at it. It looks like the data is pretty sparse right now and contains numerous errors -- my first song I tested was misspelled in the database.

Comment: Well, the bounty is running out and this is the best answer I've seen.  Ergo, I pronounce you the winner good sir.  I guess there just aren't many people outside of DJs who are really interested in this stuff.  I just wish runners would realize that setting their music to a proper BPM can affect their running.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great article written by a guy who wrote a click track detector to analyze the BPM of a song:  http://musicmachinery.com/2009/03/02/in-search-of-the-click-track/.  Interestingly, the program shows that some artists use click tracks while others do not, which could explain some of the more mysterious results you've seen in your BPM-per-song search.